# Android- Amplify configuration issue with separate apps (app and app2)

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

I'm working on an Android project that involves two separate apps, app and app2. Each app has its own Amplify configuration with Auth and API functionalities. I'm experiencing a problem when trying to save user data in the app after signing up in app2.

In the main app (app), I have the following configuration code in my initAws function:

```
// Amplify configuration in app
fun initAws(context: Context, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
    try {
        // DataStorePlugin and other plugins added
        Amplify.configure(AmplifyConfiguration.fromConfigFile(context, R.raw.amplifyconfiguration), context)
        onSuccess()
    } catch (e: AmplifyException) {
        // Exception handling code
    }
}
```

In app2, I have a separate configuration function:

```
// Amplify configuration in app2
private fun configureAws(onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
    try {
        // API and Auth plugins added
        Amplify.configure(AmplifyConfiguration.fromConfigFile(this, R.raw.amplifyconfiguration_2), this)
        onSuccess()
    } catch (e: AmplifyException) {
        // Exception handling code
    }
}
```

The flow is as follows:

1. In the mainActivity of app, I call initAws and perform signup using Amplify.Auth.signUp, which works successfully.
2. Then, I navigate to a service in app2 to perform signup using Amplify.Auth.signUp, and that also works successfully.
3. Finally, when I go back to app to save user data, it seems to point to the app2 schema and fails.

I'm not sure why the save operation in app is referencing the app2 schema instead of its own. I've double-checked the configurations and they appear to be correct.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!